# Creating a palindrome checker with Python's loop and if statements

Tags: python, loops, palindrome

I am trying to follow the instructions to create a palindrome. I am given half a function, and I have to fill in the blanks. I am currently unable to get the loop to work correctly. I am also unsure how to add characters to the beginning or the end of string without using the + or a comma. I do not think that is what I am being asked to do. 
Here are the instructions;

> The is_palindrome function checks if a string is a palindrome... Fill in the blanks in this function to return True if the passed string is a palindrome, False if not.

```
def is_palindrome(input_string):
    # We'll create two strings, to compare them
    new_string = input_string.replace(" ", "")
    reverse_string = input_string.replace(" ", "")
    # Traverse through each letter of the input string
    for word in input_string: # Originally, I was only given the a FOR statement here, I wrote in the rest
        new_string+=word.replace(" ","").upper()
        # Add any non-blank letters to the 
        # end of one string, and to the front
        # of the other string. 

    if ___:
        new_string = ___
        reverse_string = ___
    # # Compare the strings
      if ___:
          return True
          return False

print(is_palindrome("Never Odd or Even")) # Should be True
print(is_palindrome("abc")) # Should be False
print(is_palindrome("kayak")) # Should be True
```

I have removed the empty spaces and made everything the same case. I have assigned the characters to new_string, but it looks like I am supposed to use join to add the characters, but when I do the print statement does not print anything. I am unsure how to add the items in reverse order. 
I am not even sure if I am on the correct track, because I am unsure what the IF statement is asking. I would think I should be able to use a loop to create the string and then compare the two strings.

Also, could someone please explain why new_string.join(word) does not print anything out? How am I using it incorrectly?

Thank you very much for any possible assistance.

Comment: As a side note, I have also tried using

```
reverse_string = input_string[::-1].replace(" ","").upper()
```

But, I do not think that is the point. I do that then I can just do new_string == reverse_string. I think anyway. Thank you.

Comment: `def is_palindrome(input_string):
 # We'll create two strings, to compare them
  new_string = ""
  reverse_string = ""
 # Traverse through each letter of the input string
  for word in input_string:
    new_string+=word.replace(" ","").upper()
    reverse_string = new_string[::-1].replace(" ","").upper()
  if new_string == reverse_string:
   return True
  return False

print(is_palindrome("Never Odd or Even")) # Should be True
print(is_palindrome("abc")) # Should be False
print(is_palindrome("kayak")) # Should be True
`
That is what I have now, but delted first if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It worked for me**, I have tried and change little bit from above my code it work now with below code.

**You can see it pass in  their test and code verification, refer below screenshots and code.**

[image]

```
def is_palindrome(input_string):
    # We'll create two strings, to compare them
    new_string = ""
    reverse_string = ""
    # Traverse through each letter of the input string
    for letter in input_string.strip():
        # Add any non-blank letters to the 
        # end of one string, and to the front
        # of the other string. 
        new_string = new_string+letter.replace(" ","")
        reverse_string = letter.replace(" ","")+reverse_string
    # Compare the strings
    if new_string.lower() == reverse_string.lower():
        return True
    return False

print(is_palindrome("Never Odd or Even")) # Should be True
print(is_palindrome("abc")) # Should be False
print(is_palindrome("kayak")) # Should be True
```

Answer (score 1):

I run into this same quiz on coursera. Here is my answer to this question without using `.replace()` function as it is not mentioned in the course.

````py
def is_palindrome(input_string):
    # We'll create two strings, to compare them
    new_string = ""
    reverse_string = ""
    # Traverse through each letter of the input string
    for letter in input_string.lower():
        # Add any non-blank letters to the 
        # end of one string, and to the front
        # of the other string. 
        if letter != " ":
            new_string = new_string + letter
            reverse_string = letter + reverse_string
    # Compare the strings
    if new_string == reverse_string:
        return True
    return False

print(is_palindrome("Never Odd or Even")) # Should be True
print(is_palindrome("abc")) # Should be False
print(is_palindrome("kayak")) # Should be True
```python
````

Answer (score 0):

```py
def is_palindrome(input_string):
 new_string = input_string.replace(" ", "").lower()
 reverse_string = input_string.replace(" ", "").lower()[::-1]
if new_string == reverse_string:
        return True
    return False

> This should do it.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written this program,
It returns expected result as well, but it is getting rejected.
Don`t know what exactly they test internally to validate code and its correctness.
**My implementation :**

```
def is_palindrome(input_string):
    # We'll create two strings, to compare them
    new_string = ""
    reverse_string = ""
    # Traverse through each letter of the input string
    for letter in input_string.strip():
        # Add any non-blank letters to the 
        # end of one string, and to the front
        # of the other string. 
        if letter !=' ':
            new_string = new_string+letter
            reverse_string = letter+reverse_string
    # Compare the strings
    if new_string.lower() == reverse_string.lower():
        return True
    return False

print(is_palindrome("Never Odd or Even")) # Should be True
print(is_palindrome("abc")) # Should be False
print(is_palindrome("kayak")) # Should be True
```

[image]

If any one knows what exactly i am missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

**It worked for me**, This code what the system expected to see.

```
def is_palindrome(input_string):
    # We'll create two strings, to compare them
    new_string = ""
    reverse_string = ""
    # Traverse through each letter of the input string
    for word in input_string:
        # Add any non-blank letters to the 
        # end of one string, and to the front
        # of the other string. 
        word = word.lower()
        if word != " ":
            new_string = new_string + word
            reverse_string = word + reverse_string
    # Compare the strings
    if new_string == reverse_string:
        return True
    return False

print(is_palindrome("Never Odd or Even")) # Should be True
print(is_palindrome("abc")) # Should be False
print(is_palindrome("kayak")) # Should be True
```

[is_palindrome function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADpxR.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_palindrome(input_string):
    # We'll create two strings, to compare them
    new_string = ""
    reverse_string = ""
    # Traverse through each letter of the input string
    for char in input_string:
        # Add any non-blank letters to the 
        # end of one string, and to the front
        # of the other string.
        if char !=" ":
            new_string +=char.lower() 

            reverse_string =char.lower()+reverse_string

    # Compare the strings
    if new_string==reverse_string:
        return True
    return False

print(is_palindrome("Never Odd or Even")) # Should be True
print(is_palindrome("abc")) # Should be False
print(is_palindrome("kayak")) # Should be True
```

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple one . The main approach is

1. Convert the given string into lower-case
2. Check for white space ""
3. Insert into new strings

   ```
       new_string = new_string+i
       reverse_string = i+reverse_string
   ```
4. Check if new-string == reverse_string

CODE :

```
# We'll create two strings, to compare them

input_string = input_string.lower()
new_string = ""
reverse_string = ""
# Traverse through each letter of the input string
for i in input_string:
    # Add any non-blank letters to the 
    # end of one string, and to the front
    # of the other string. 
    if i !=" ":
        new_string = new_string+i
        reverse_string = i+reverse_string
# Compare the strings
if new_string == reverse_string:
    return True
return False

print(is_palindrome("Never Odd or Even")) # Should be True
print(is_palindrome("abc")) # Should be False
print(is_palindrome("kayak")) # Should be True
```

OUTPUT

```
 True 
 False
 True
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
def is_palindrome(input_string):
    # We'll create two strings, to compare them
    new_string = input_string.replace(" ", "")
    new_string = new_string.lower()
    reverse_string = new_string[::-1]
    reverse_string = reverse_string.lower()
    # Traverse through each letter of the input string
    if new_string == reverse_string:
        return True
    return False


print(is_palindrome("Never Odd or Even"))  # Should be True
print(is_palindrome("abc"))  # Should be False
print(is_palindrome("kayak"))  # Should be True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_palindrome(input_string):

    # We'll create two strings, to compare them
    new_string = ""
    reverse_string = ""
    # Traverse througenter code hereh each letter of the input string
    for letter in input_string.strip().lower():
        # Add any non-blank letters to the 
        # end of one string, and to the front
        # of the other string. 
        if letter!=" ":
            new_string = new_string+letter
            reverse_string = letter+reverse_string
    # Compare the strings
    if new_string==reverse_string:
        return True
    return False
```

Then:

```
print(is_palindrome("Never Odd or Even")) # Should be True

print(is_palindrome("abc")) # Should be False

print(is_palindrome("kayak")) # Should be True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_palindrome(input_string):
    new_string = ""
    reverse_string = ""
    
    for word in input_string:
        if word != " ":
            new_string = new_string.strip().lower() + word
            reverse_string = word + reverse_string.strip().lower()
    # Compare the strings
    if new_string == reverse_string:
        return True
    return False

print(is_palindrome("Never Odd or Even")) # Should be True
print(is_palindrome("abc")) # Should be False
print(is_palindrome("kayak")) # Should be True
```

Answer (score 0):

The `strip()` or `replace()` functions aren't necessarily useful in this case.

The `strip()` method won't remove spaces between each word in a phrase i.e. the first case 'Never Odd or Even'.

Hence, a simple if statement will do the job.

Don't forget to convert your strings to `upper()` or `lower()` cases.

```py
def is_palindrome(input_string):
    # We'll create two strings, to compare them
    new_string = ""
    reverse_string = ""
    # Traverse through each letter of the input string
    for letter in input_string.lower():
        # Add any non-blank letters to the 
        # end of one string, and to the front
        # of the other string. 
        if letter!=" ":
            new_string += letter
            reverse_string = letter + reverse_string
    # Compare the strings
    if new_string == reverse_string:
        return True
    return False
print(is_palindrome("Never Odd or Even")) # Should be True
print(is_palindrome("abc")) # Should be False
print(is_palindrome("kayak")) # Should be True
```

Answer (score 0):

I have some spare time so I try to manually indexing and **it works for me :D**

```
def is_palindrome(input_string):
    input_string = input_string.lower().replace(" ", "") '''make the string have 
                                    lower letter remove the withspace'''
    new_string = ""
    reverse_string = ""
    for n in range(len(input_string)):
        new_string += input_string[n]
        reverse_string += input_string[(len(input_string)-(1+n))] '''manually make string 
                                                from behind with indexing.'''
    if new_string == reverse_string:
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_palindrome(input_string):
    new_string = input_string.lower()
    no_space = new_string.replace(" ","")

    reverse_string =new_string.replace(" ","")[::-1]
    if reverse_string==no_space:
        return True
    return False

print(is_palindrome("Never Odd or Even")) # Should be True
print(is_palindrome("abc")) # Should be False
print(is_palindrome("kayak")) # Should be True
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This worked perfectly well for me

```
def is_palindrome(input_string):
    # We'll create two strings, to compare them
    new_string = ""
    reverse_string = ""
    # Traverse through each letter of the input string
    for letter in input_string.lower():
        # Add any non-blank letters to the 
        # end of one string, and to the front
        # of the other string. 
        if letter != " ":
            new_string = new_string + letter
            reverse_string = letter + reverse_string
    if new_string == reverse_string:
        return True
    return False

print(is_palindrome("Never Odd or Even")) # Should be True
print(is_palindrome("abc")) # Should be False
print(is_palindrome("kayak")) # Should be True
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).